# What is the best dictionary for learning a contemporary American accent?

Tags: dictionaries, accent, north-american-english

I’m using the *Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary* (18<sup>th</sup> edition, 2011). I know how IPA phonemes work and can also fathom American notations. So, which dictionary would best help a rookie to learn a *contemporary* American accent? Don’t suggest age-old dictionaries.

Comment: The Google lady on Google translate's "listen" feature (if the Google settings are US English) does a pretty good job of speaking individual words, and often entire phrases with a natural accent and intonation. Always best to check on ell.stackexchange.com if you encounter anything that sounds odd.  For example, this is pretty close to natural accent and phonology: `a paper bag` https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate&oq=google+translate&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64j69i60.1895j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources

Comment: @FumbleFingers where can i request resources? looking for the best etymological dictionary, or starters...

Comment: @user3293056: The gold standard is the full OED (Oxford English Dictionary). There's nothing remotely comparable, for English or any other language. Sadly, unless you can get free access through your university (or UK public library), [it costs $295/year](http://public.oed.com/how-to-subscribe/). The best etymological dictionary with free online access is [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/), but see [this ELU Meta page](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/484/) for a more complete list of what we at ELU consider "reliable, online resources".

Answer (score 3):

None: you cannot pick up an accent from a dictionary. You can only pick up an accent from listening to it.

There’s far, far, far more to an accent than its phonology alone, let alone that part of its phonology readily expressible in IPA.  Note also that most dictionaries at best use phonemic transcriptions, not phonetic ones.  A phonemic transcription will not be enough to tell someone just learning the language how it is to be pronounced phonetically.

The [Wikipedia article on *accent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_(sociolinguistics)) points this out in the following citation:

> Many adult and near-adult learners of second languages have unintelligible speech patterns that may interfere with their education, profession, and social interactions. **Pronunciation in a second or foreign language involves more than the correct articulation of individual sounds.** It involves producing a wide range of complex and subtle distinctions which relate sound to meaning at several levels.

Comment: True. However, if you want the correct American pronunciation for English words, the best (and by far the most convenient) source is [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/stream/pronouncingdicti00unse?ui=embed#page/6/mode/1up). It also has a lot of practical information about regional dialects and English in America,

Comment: It depends on which American accent you want: broadcast, New York, mid west, southern, Appalachian, Texan, Boston, etc...

Comment: Curse Twitter and Facebook for prose and enjoy Youtube for pronunciation.  English is so alive.  I doubt any published source (I assume you mean a published dictionary) can keep up.

Comment: "Curse Twitter and Facebook for prose." As apposite as the word you used may sometimes seem, I suspect you intended *cruise*. @user116032.